# How to empty Jenkins scheduled job list

Tags: rest, jenkins, jobs

I'm using Jenkins Rest API to build and schedule job.
The problem that i schedule one job for the Week-end but it execute it several times (Same job executed every minute).
For the rest of the week the job is executed only once, so if there any GUI options to empty the week-end job list ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following groovy script to clean all ( or part of your queue ....)

this example delete all jobs that start with a specific branch name

```
import jenkins.model.*

def branchName = build.environment.get("GIT_BRANCH_NAME")

println "=========before clean the queue ... =="

def q = Jenkins.instance.queue
q.items.each { 
  println("${it.task.name}:")
}

q.items.findAll { it.task.name.startsWith(branchName) }.each { q.cancel(it.task) }


println "=========after clean the queue ... =="
q = Jenkins.instance.queue
q.items.each { 
  println("${it.task.name}:")
}
```

Comment: you can run it in your script console your-jenkins:8080/script , or install the groovy plugin